# Angular - Search for multiple keys inside array of objects

Tags: javascript, angular, filter, include

**The array of objects:**

```
array = [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "key": "key1",
        "name": "name1",
        "area": "area1",
        "functionalArea": "func1",
        "lob": "lob1",
    },
{
        "id": 2,
        "key": "key2",
        "name": "name2",
        "area": "ALL",
        "functionalArea": "ALL",
        "lob": "ALL",
    },
]
```

**My atempt**:

```
const { name, id, functionalArea, area, lob } = this.form.getRawValue();
    const searchTerms = {
      widgetName,
      widgetId,
      functionalArea,
      area,
      lob,
    };

.subscribe(
        (res) => {
          let results = array.filter((item) =>
          searchTerms.functionalArea === 'ALL' &&
          searchTerms.area === 'ALL' &&
          searchTerms.lob === 'ALL' &&
          !searchTerms.id &&
          !searchTerms.name
            ? item
            : item.key.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.widgetId.toLowerCase()) ||
              item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.widgetName.toLowerCase()) ||
              (item.functionalArea.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.functionalArea.toLowerCase()) &&
                item.area.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.area.toLowerCase()) &&
                item.lob.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.lob.toLowerCase()))
          );
        },
```

**The problem:**
I cannot filter for multiple conditions using includes() function, it does not work.
If i remove all conditions and use only one than the includes() function works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A filter is a function that return true or false, As always you want to "search" is good at first convert to upperCase (or lowerCase) the "condition"

```
searchTerms.functionalArea=searchTerms.functionalArea?
                           searchTerms.functionalArea.toLowerCase():'ALL'
searchTerms.area =searchTerms.functionalArea?
                           searchTerms.area.toLowerCase():'ALL'
searchTerms.lob =searchTerms.functionalArea?
                           searchTerms.lob.toLowerCase():'ALL'
searchTerms.name=searchTerms.name?
                           searchTerms.name.toLowerCase():'ALL'

const result=array.filter((item)=>{ //<--see this bracket

     let result=searchTerms.functionalArea=='ALL' || 
                searchTerms.functionalArea.includes(item.functionalArea.toLowerCase());

     result=result && (searchTerms.area =='ALL' || 
                       searchTerms.area.includes(item.area .toLowerCase());)

     result=result && (searchTerms.lob =='ALL' || 
                       searchTerms.lob.includes(item.lob .toLowerCase());)

     //Update

     result=result && (!searchTerms.widgetId || 
                          searchTerms.widgetId==item.id)

     result=result && (!searchTerms.widgetName || 
                       searchTerms.widgetName.includes(item.name.toLowerCase());)

     return result; //<--as you use bracket, you should use return
})
```

Comment: It almost there. I´m trying to make the id and name keys to work also, but for now it is not working.

Comment: I update the quaestion adding the two missing comparisions. BTW I like that the searchTerm properties has the same name that the "item" (name instead of widgetName and id instead of id) because is more "comfortable" the comparations. NOTE2: sound "strange" use toLowerCase and that was "ALL" (in upper case)

Comment: Well, i have writen exactly the same as your update before you made it and is not able to find the name or the id, in console.log it returns false.
Tried your updated code and its the same. Not working for the name or the id, the rest works well.
Not sure what is the problem, your updated answer should have worked.

Comment: check using `console.log(searchTerms.widgetId,item.id,searchTerms.widgetName,item.name)`, even you can use `console.log((!searchTerms.widgetId || searchTerms.widgetId==item.id))`

Comment: I had to make some changes like conditional use search cases if(...), amongst others, and now it is working as expected. Your answer gave me some great insights on how to solve the problem, so i will mark it as accepted. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You have to filter only if the conditions about searchTerm are true, something like this:

```
let results = (searchTerms.functionalArea === 'ALL' &&
                searchTerms.area === 'ALL' &&
                searchTerms.lob === 'ALL' &&
                !searchTerms.id &&
                !searchTerms.name) 
            ? array 
            : array.filter((item) => item.key.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.widgetId.toLowerCase()) ||
            item.name.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.widgetName.toLowerCase()) ||
            (item.functionalArea.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.functionalArea.toLowerCase()) &&
              item.area.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.area.toLowerCase()) &&
              item.lob.toLowerCase().includes(searchTerms.lob.toLowerCase())));
```

EXAMPLE (check the console output): https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-y2w6sr?file=index.ts

Comment: It didnt work. I know its a hard task...

Comment: @AndréCastro You can try with a method: (prev part)... : array.filter(item) => this.filter(item)) and return a bool from the method

Comment: @AndréCastro it's working https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-y2w6sr?file=index.ts

Comment: Thanks... in the demo its working but in my local dev it is not. I'm trying to figure it out.